# console error when using getElementsAtEventForMode

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm trying to call the function `getElementsAtEventForMode()` in my chart.js doughnut chart, but i keep getting this error message in console: `chart.getElementsAtEventsForMode is not a function`.

```
       // Pass the canvas ID
        let myChart = Chart.getChart('myChart');

        //updating chart with new values each time a value is selected
        if (myChart) {
            myChart.data.labels = legend;
            myChart.data.datasets[0].data = stats;
            myChart.config.options.plugins.title.text = "Top 5 causes of death in " + country;
            myChart.update();
        } else {
            new Chart('myChart', config);
        }

        //detecting click on doughnut sections for modal
        this.clickHandler = function (onclick) {
            const points = myChart.getElementsAtEventForMode(onclick, 'nearest', { intersect: true }, true);

            if (points[0]) {
                modal.classList.toggle('hide');
            }
        }

        addEventListener("click", this.clickHandler);
```

Comment: You're calling `getElementsAtEventForMode` on `Chart` instead of your chart instance (`chart`).

Answer (score 2):

You can't use the global chart instance, you need to use your chart instance to call the function like so:

```js
const chartInstance = Chart.getChart(canvasId);

const points = chartInstance.getElementsAtEventForMode("click", 'nearest', { intersect: true }, true);
```

Comment: i tried ur code but it still displays this error: ```Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getElementsAtEventForMode')```

Comment: That means you don't have a chart on a canvas which id you passed to the getChart function

Comment: but i did pass the same canvas id which my chart is on though..

Comment: Then it has to work, can you provide a reproducable sample?

Comment: I updated the post with the current code I'm using. The funny thing is everything seems to be working fine just some slight delays of the modal opening when clicking on certain areas of my doughnut chart.

Answer (score 0):

In Chartjs, it has getElementsAtEventForMode not eventsForMode..
use

```
Chart.getElementsAtEventForMode
```

instead of

```
Chart.getElementsAtEventsForMode
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same error

Comment: use Chart instead of params chart..

Comment: I updated it but unfortunately its still showing the same error message